# Extract block of text that starts with 'Block 4' until it encounters 'Block 5' from text file in Java

Tags: java

I have a text file that contains three messages, each message contains Block 4 content. What I want to achieve is that I want to get all the content inside Block 4. (Skipping the remaining content). Here is my code that extracts Message 1 Block 4. How do I get the Block 4 content of the remaining messages?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException {
    String filePath = "C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\reportTest5.txt";
     
    String content = null;
    try {
        // read the file
        content = readFile(filePath);
        
        // parse the file
        List<AlphabetSpellings> fileParsing = parseFile(content);
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static String readFile(String path) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(path)));
    return reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
}

private static List<AlphabetSpellings> parseFile(String fileContent) {

    // create list object

    String block4 = fileContent.indexOf("Block 5") == -1 ? ""
            : fileContent.substring(fileContent.indexOf("Block 4") + 8, fileContent.indexOf("Block 5"));

    // add block4 to list object
    
    System.out.println(block4);

    // return list as null for now
    return null;
}
```

[image: Text file content]

Comment: indexOf return the index of the first match so you can do one of the following use indexOf that take 2 paramter the string you looking for and the startindex you want to search from check the api https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,int) another way to use the regex  and here a tutorial for it https://dev.java/learn/regex/ and if you stuck with anything replay to my comment and update your code and i will help :)

Comment: I have done this in another way.

Comment: congratulations well done :)